# Automapper with MVC and modified nested entities - how to update them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I'm using automapper to map my entities to a viewmodel, and form the viewmodel back to the entity on the trip back from the view.

I've got a little problem, I have a nested entities list in my modified object, which can be modified in the view. When I save the main object, even if everything seems correctly mapped in its nested entities, the nested entities are not updated (no SQL statements related to them are seen in the console).

I'm pretty sure there is something I miss to make sure that EF knows they have been modified.

The only thing I found, is to notify the framework the entities have been modified (even if not all of them are) in my controller:

```
Database.Entry(character).State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach(CharacterAbilityScore cab in character.CharacterAbilityScores)
    Database.Entry(cab).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

If I remember correctly, when I was using the entities instead of ViewModels in my view, I didn't need to notify EF that the nested entities were modified, it knew and updated the database accordingly.

I just want to make sure I have the correct approach.

Tell me if you need more code!

**UPDATE:**

This is how I configured automapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CharacterViewModel, Character>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CharacterAbilityScores, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CharacterAbilityScoresDTO));
```

**Final update, answer:**

Since I'm in MVC mode, and the context is recreated when we come back from the post on the view, I have to manually manage how my child entities have changed, either with self tracking entities or like I did, marking them modified when I know they will likely be. It will result in a bit more updates than necessary though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm in MVC mode, and the context is recreated when I come back from the post on the view, Entity Framework can only track the parent object, not the nested ones.

So I have to manually manage how my child entities have changed, either with self tracking entities or like I did, marking them modified when I know they will likely be. It will result in a bit more updates than necessary though.

So, either by using self tracking entities (see this blog post) http://blog.tonysneed.com/2013/11/18/trackable-entities-versus-self-tracking-entities/ or marked them as "modified" like I did in my original question (which result in more updates than necessary, can be acceptable if still small amount).

Answer (score 2):

You need to map your collection independently of your main entity. Otherwise, AutoMapper replaces the entire collection with the mapped classes instead of actually mapping the new values onto the existing items.

In your config, tell AutoMapper to ignore your collection when mapping:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<CharacterViewModel, Character>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CharacterAbilityScores, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Then, map the posted data in two steps in your action:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(model, character);
foreach (var item in model.CharacterAbilityScores)
{
    var existingItem = character.CharacterAbilityScores.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == item.Id);
    if (existingItem == null)
    {
        character.CharacterAbilityScores.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CharacterAbilityScore>(item));
    }
    else
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(item, existingItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not fun... :) It's surprising for me that even if the collection was correctly matched in the entity with my mapping config, EF could not get them to update by itself, do you know if there a reason?

Comment: It's because of the object tracking EF does. By mapping an entirely new collection in place of the old one, you're telling EF that it should delete all those old items, and then add these new items. By manually setting the state to modified, you're causing EF to attach those new items and switch to an update mode instead.

Comment: Chris, when I didn't notice EF to modify, it didn't do ANYTHING with the collection. No deletes and recreates, no updates, nothing. That's why I'm a bit lost. I also find it quite bizarre that I cannot automap the child entities (I updated my question to add how I configured the automapper for this)

Comment: And there is a problem with your solution, since the mapping is ignored, the collection is empty, so it creates an entry for each items in the collection, and the savechanges fails since there is already entries in the database. Maybe you meant I should compare with what's in the DB and not in the Character object mapped from the VM?